# openVPN on AWS free tier via RoadWarrior - connecting, but no internet

Tags: firewall, openvpn, amazon-web-services

My new home internet is too slow for a personal openVPN server for protecting myself when not at home, so I decided to use the amazon AWS free tier server I got a few months back and never did anything with. I got excited when speedtest-cli reported the connection speed was about 500mbps up and down, way more then enough for a VPN for one person. I used roadwarrior to install openVPN, just as I did on my server on my old internet, and connected. Much to my surprise, I have no access to the outside web. I know I am connected, because I can connect SSH to 10.8.0.1 and get a remote shell to my AWS machine. However, I get 100% packet loss when trying to ping anything

I disabled the default AWS firewall thingy and setup UFW instead, and allowed port 1194 thru UFW, but I don't think firewall rules are the problem as I can connect to the actual VPN itself just fine.

The clients are an arch linux laptop and an android

I'm using UDP

Terminal output: https://haste.gradyn.com/MNu3PPOIoS.pl

Comment: What does 'nslookup www.google.com' gives you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason openVPN isn't automatically editing resolv.conf so DNS won't work. I simply have to manually set my DNS servers